# SQLite3 creating a view profit combining rows twice based on column

Tags: sqlite

Given a table

```
symbol|action|quantity|price
foo|buy|1|-10.00
foo|sell|1|10.50
bar|buy|1|-50.00
bar|sell|1|50.50
```

I am trying to create a view that shows profit per symbol

I've tried several variations of below with multiple 'order by' but not getting the expected output

```
create view if not exists profit_view as select symbol,sum(price * quanity) as profit from trans group by symbol;
```

What I'd like is a view that shows or something close to that

```
symbol|profit|percent
foo|.50|5
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each symbol only has a single buy and sell record we can try:

```
SELECT
    symbol,
    SUM(quantity*price) AS profit,
    100.0 * SUM(quantity*price) /
        ABS(MAX(CASE WHEN action = 'buy' THEN quantity*price END)) AS percent
FROM trans
GROUP BY
    symbol;
```